# Modify Code - Copy Range to another Spreadsheet Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The code below copies range and moves to next Spreadsheet in same workbook called "Topup Required".

I would like it to send this data to another spreadsheet inside another workbook instead.

```
 function onEdit(event) {
// assumes source data in sheet named PrepSheet
// target sheet of move to named TOP UP NEEDED
// getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to column I
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
if(s.getName() == "PrepSheet" && r.getColumn() == 9 && r.getValue() == true) {
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("TOP UP NEEDED");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);

 }
 }
```

I tried replacing

```
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("TOP UP NEEDED");
```

with

```
var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheet ID").getSheetByName("TOP UP NEEDED");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
```

but it didnt work

Could anyone tell me where i went wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to copy the values and format from `s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns)` to the last row on the sheet of `TOP UP NEEDED` in the Spreadsheet of `sheet ID`, when the cell is edited.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Modification point:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, `copyTo()` of Class range cannot be used for other Spreadsheet.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, `copyTo()` is used. So both the values and the cell format are copied.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("TOP UP NEEDED");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
```

To:

```
var targetSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheet ID");
s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var tempSheet = s.copyTo(targetSS);
var targetSheet = targetSS.getSheetByName("TOP UP NEEDED");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
tempSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
targetSS.deleteSheet(tempSheet);
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, `getValues()` and `appendRow()` are used. So only the values are copied.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("TOP UP NEEDED");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
```

To:

```
var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheet ID").getSheetByName("TOP UP NEEDED");
var sourceValues = s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues()[0];
targetSheet.appendRow(sourceValues);
```

### Note: IMPORTANT

- In this modification, the simple trigger of `onEdit()` cannot be used. An error occurs at `openById()`. So please use the installable trigger of OnEdit event trigger. In this case, please modify the function name as follows.

  - From

    ```
    function onEdit(event) {
    ```
  - To

    ```
    function installedOnEdit(event) {
    ```
  - After this modification, [please install the OnEdit event trigger to `installedOnEdit` as the installable trigger.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) By this, when the cell is edited, `installedOnEdit` is run without the double executions. Please be careful this.

### References:

- [copyTo(destination) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination)
- [copyTo(spreadsheet) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet))
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [appendRow(rowContents)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object))
- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Tanaike - I think you posted that answer to wrong person ? You have answered my question and code is doing exactly what I needed it to do. Thanks very much

Comment: @Tanaike I am so grateful to you for this. Thank you very much

Comment: @hiep Hoangduc Thank you for your comment. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.