# Copying Conditional Format Rule from One Sheet to Another in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to copy a simple conditional format rule from one sheet to another in the same Google Sheets file. Here is the simplest setup that replicates the problem I'm running into:

Imagine a Google Sheets file with only two sheets: `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`. I set a conditional format rule on cell `B2` in `Sheet1` that says if that cell is not empty then format it (the default format that pops up when is a green background). That's it. I want to copy that to Sheet2.

The method I tried is based on the accepted solution in this question: [How to copy conditional formatting between different spreadsheets in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63879099/how-to-copy-conditional-formatting-between-different-spreadsheets-in-google-apps)

And here is my code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var rules = sourceSheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  targetSheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}
```

The above generates an exception though:

> Exception: Conditional format rule cannot reference a different sheet.

I've tried to play with the `copy()` method of the `ConditionalFormatRule` class with no luck. I get the same error. I also checked that when I use the `getRanges()` method on the rule object I get A1 notation references to the range in question (cell `B2`) without any reference to `Sheet1`, so I'm not even sure where the "reference to a different sheet" is!

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: I also tried the accepted solution [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63879099/how-to-copy-conditional-formatting-between-different-spreadsheets-in-google-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63879099/how-to-copy-conditional-formatting-between-different-spreadsheets-in-google-apps) but it didn't work for me and I'm getting **Exception: Conditional format rule cannot reference a different sheet.** Are you considering using newConditionalFormatRule class and use your Sheet1 as reference?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below:

```
function myFunction() {
 var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
 var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  
var sslr=sourceSheet.getLastRow()
var sslc=sourceSheet.getLastColumn()
var tslr=targetSheet.getLastRow()
var tslc=targetSheet.getLastColumn()

sourceSheet.getRange(1,1,sslr,sslc).copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(1,1,tslr,tslc), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_CONDITIONAL_FORMATTING, false)
}
```

Comment: That only pastes the color rules

Comment: @Cooper maybe I misunderstood the OP.  How did you interpret the request?

Comment: It wasn't meant to be a criticism ... just added information.

Comment: Yes.  Just the color rules.  No additional formatting.

Comment: This solution seems to work in the examples I'm testing, but it sounds from @Cooper's comment like there may be other types of conditional format rules where this wouldn't work? Could you please clarify what you mean by "color rules" @Cooper? What would be an example of a conditional format rule that is not a "color rule"?

Comment: I believe Cooper was just noting that this only pastes the conditional formatting, not all formatting, which, as I understand, is what you required.